# How to convert date/time strings that have 24 as the hour value to datetimes in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I'm importing emails as text files from a common mail app (Mac OS X).  Unfortunately, many of the dates on the emails have times like `"24:01:01"` which is not a valid time (should be `"00:01:01"`).

Is there an easy way to convert these?

Normal date/time string works fine:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime("March 23, 2011 at 23:42:46  PDT")
Timestamp('2011-03-23 23:42:46-0700', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(-420)')
```

Abnormal datestring:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime("March 23, 2011 at 24:42:46  PDT")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda/envs/pyqt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   1860         try:
-> 1861             values, tz_parsed = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(data)
   1862             # If tzaware, these values represent unix timestamps, so we

pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-4cb009b21802> in <module>
----> 1 pd.to_datetime("March 23, 2011 at 24:42:46  PDT")

~/anaconda/envs/pyqt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, box, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    609             result = convert_listlike(arg, box, format)
    610     else:
--> 611         result = convert_listlike(np.array([arg]), box, format)[0]
    612 
    613     return result

~/anaconda/envs/pyqt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, box, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    300             arg, dayfirst=dayfirst, yearfirst=yearfirst,
    301             utc=utc, errors=errors, require_iso8601=require_iso8601,
--> 302             allow_object=True)
    303 
    304     if tz_parsed is not None:

~/anaconda/envs/pyqt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   1864             return values.view('i8'), tz_parsed
   1865         except (ValueError, TypeError):
-> 1866             raise e
   1867 
   1868     if tz_parsed is not None:

~/anaconda/envs/pyqt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py in objects_to_datetime64ns(data, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, errors, require_iso8601, allow_object)
   1855             dayfirst=dayfirst,
   1856             yearfirst=yearfirst,
-> 1857             require_iso8601=require_iso8601
   1858         )
   1859     except ValueError as e:

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime()

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime_object()

pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime_object()

pandas/_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string()

~/anaconda/envs/pyqt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py in parse(timestr, parserinfo, **kwargs)
   1354         return parser(parserinfo).parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1355     else:
-> 1356         return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1357 
   1358 

~/anaconda/envs/pyqt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py in parse(self, timestr, default, ignoretz, tzinfos, **kwargs)
    651             raise ValueError("String does not contain a date:", timestr)
    652 
--> 653         ret = self._build_naive(res, default)
    654 
    655         if not ignoretz:

~/anaconda/envs/pyqt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py in _build_naive(self, res, default)
   1225                 repl['day'] = monthrange(cyear, cmonth)[1]
   1226 
-> 1227         naive = default.replace(**repl)
   1228 
   1229         if res.weekday is not None and not res.day:

ValueError: hour must be in 0..23
```

Comment: What value do you expect from this? 0:42:46 on the next day?

Comment: @Paul yes I'm expecting 00:42:46 on the next day.

Comment: Not sure where these time strings are coming from.  May be the Apple Mail Mac perhaps or from the mail services that were used to create the original emails.  Here is how they appear in the email text files: `Date: February 24, 2011 at 24:48:03  PST`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert good datetimes with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` - get `NaT` for bad values. So filter it, `replace` `24` and add one day. Last [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace missing values by it:

```
d = ["March 23, 2011 at 24:42:46  PDT",
     "March 23, 2011 at 23:42:46  PDT"]

s = pd.Series(d)

s1 = pd.to_datetime(s, errors='coerce')
m = s1.isna()

s2 = (pd.to_datetime(s[m].replace('at 24:', 'at 00:', regex=True),  errors='coerce') +
         pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))

s = s1.fillna(s2)
print (s)
0   2011-03-24 00:42:46
1   2011-03-23 23:42:46
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Another idea - extract days and times to separate columns and add `timedelta`s:

```
s1 = pd.to_datetime(s, errors='coerce')
m = s1.isna()

df2 = s[m].str.split(' at ', expand=True)
df2.columns = ['date','time']
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'], errors='coerce')
df2['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df2['time'].str.extract('(\d+:\d+:\d+)', expand=False))
df2['date1'] = df2['date'] + df2['time']
print (df2)
        date            time               date1
0 2011-03-23 1 days 00:42:46 2011-03-24 00:42:46

s = s1.fillna(df2['date1'])
print (s)
0   2011-03-24 00:42:46
1   2011-03-23 23:42:46
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```